# [Java]Consulta concatenar etiqueta de botones precionados

Tags: java, string

Hola amigos una consulta rápida y guía  ya que me estoy rompiendo la cabeza y no se me ocurre nada quisiera saber si opinión y/o ayuda, el programa consiste en un simulador de boletos de autobuses que a presionar el boton se aparte el asiento y cuando se presione un boton especial este me muestre una cadena string que almacene la label de los botones por ejemplo al presionar el boton ver me muestre una etiqueta + la cadena con los asientos ocupados como "asientos ocupados: 0 1 3 4 5 ... 44"

espero sus respuestas y agradecería su ayuda.

```
public class boletosAutobus extends Frame implements ActionListener {
Button botones[]=new Button[45];
Button boton2;
Label disponibilidad=new Label("Disponibles: 44 ");
int turno=0;
int ocupados=0;
int vacios=44;
public boletosAutobus(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,11));
        for(int i=0; i<44; i++){
            add(botones[i]=new Button(""+i));
            botones[i].addActionListener(this);
    botones[i].setBackground(Color.green);
        }
    add(boton2 = new Button("ver"));
setSize(1150, 600); setVisible(true);
    add(disponibilidad);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Button btn=(Button)e.getSource();
        int nombre = Integer.parseInt(btn.getLabel());
        btn.setLabel("R");
        btn.setBackground(Color.red);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
            vacios--;
            disponibilidad.setText("Disponibles: " + String.valueOf(vacios));
            //System.out.println(nombre);
      }
public static void main(String s[]){ new boletosAutobus(); }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el `btn.getLabel()` te trae el número de asiento, basta con que crees un `ArrayList<int>` global y cada vez que se pulse un botón, añadas `nombre`a este ArrayList.

Luego cuando quieras visualizar los asientos que se han reservado, ordenas el arrayList con `Collections.sort(nombreDelArrayList)` y lo recorres para formar un String,  tal que así:

```
StringBuilder ocupados = new StringBuilder();
for (int asiento : nombreDelArrayList)
{
    ocupados.append(String.valueOf(asiento));
    ocupados.append(", ");
}
```

Y listo!

Comment: gracias no lo había visto pensé que no me contestaron deja ver si lo puedo implementar gracias.